# UILable numberoflines and font size automatically set during zoom in out time

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uilabel, uipinchgesturerecognizer

My requires is as below.

i have a added `UILable` inside `UIView width & height is 30`.  i have set `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to that `UIView`.   Pinch in out functionality is working fine with UIView.

But my i want that when i zoom in `UILable` font size and `numberOfLine` automatically set in that `UIView`.

So at initial `UILable` not visible in View. When i Zoom in that time `UILable` get the are to display `text` so than `UILable` will be visible (ex. This time in 3 line). If i increase the Zoom level than text will be display in one row.

how can archive this functionality  ?

See the below screenshot What i want to do

[image]
******** Image 1 *****************

[image] 
******** Image 2 *****************

[image]
******** Image 3 *****************

Thanks in Advance ..

Comment: see this link its useful text with zoom in/out and rotate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038304/is-this-coretext-aviary-text-pinch-zoom-expand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this: [resize all subview in scrollViewDidZoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856928/resize-all-subview-in-scrollviewdidzoom/19900605#19900605)
On `scrollViewDidZoom` you can set the font size proportionally to zoomScale. I would suggest to set `numberOfLines` to 0 on label, but of course you can set it manually too when zooming in/out.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the delegate to detect when the zoom changes, and make your label visible then:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
     if (scrollView.zoomScale > minimunScaleToShowZoom)
     {
         myLabel.hidden = NO;
     }
     else
     {
        myLabel.hidden = YES;
     }
}
```

Play with different values for `minimunScaleToShowZoom` and check which one suits you.

Comment: i dont want only lable hide and show.  NumberofLines will be also maintain when UIView zoom in out. Currently i am trying with UIScrollView zoom in/out funcationality but not getting the success.. Do you have any idea ?